# Generic abstract class inheritance

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

**Explanation:**

I have an abstract class like so:

```
public abstract class Serializer<T> where T : new()
{
    T obj { get; set; }

    public string ToXML()
    {
        // return string XML
    }
}
```

And another class that inherits this abstract class:

```
public class Account : Serializer<Account>
{
    // Code
    // I don't want to have to implement the methods of 
    // the inherited class/interface.

}
```

I want to access it like such:

```
Account account = new Account();
Console.WriteLine(account.ToXML());
```

**Question:**

Can I do this and pass the `account` to the property `obj` so the `ToXML` can perform its task of converting the object to a string?

```
Serializer s = new Serializer();
s.ToXML(account);
```

I'd prefer to have each object inherit the `Serialize` class and all its methods, and just be able to know that without editing anything but adding the inheritance of the class that I can now access these methods.

On another note, I feel like inheriting a class violates the **is-a** and **can-do** principles between choosing an interface or a class, but I don't want to override all the methods, when I already have the code written to do it generically in a class (i.e., I don't want to implement the interface). Is there a way to inherit the methods of an interface like a class (no implementing/overriding).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to return `this`:

```
T obj { get { return (T)this; } }
```

But, this means that the child class has to provide itself as a type parameter, it's the curiously recurring "template" pattern... To be sure though, you don't necessarily need to know the type of the object at compile time to serialize it to XML (if you use the usual serializers), so accessing `this` within the serializer method would be OK, without the need for that type parameter and that property.

I'd personally prefer a more [*hands off* approach](http://codecrafter.blogspot.ca/2010/02/c-quasi-mixins-pattern.html) to an abstract base class (using the [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

```
public interface MXmlSerializable { }
public static class XmlSerializable {
  public static string ToXml(this MXmlSerializable self) {
    if (self == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(self.GetType());
    using (var writer = new StringWriter()) {
      serializer.Serialize(writer, self);
      return writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
  }
}
```

`M` stands for *mixin*. It's effectively a marker interface with an extension method. Use it like this:

```
public class Account : MXmlSerializable { 
  ... 
}

...

Account account = new Account();
...
string accountXml = account.ToXml();
```

Answer (score 0):

What about just doing it like this;

```
public string ToXML()
    {
        convert `this` to xml directly  
        // return string XML
    }
```

Why do you need the property to return a reference to the class itself.

With the above structure you can do the following, without even needing the `T` property

```
Account account = new Account();
Console.WriteLine(account.ToXML());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your construct hardly makes sense. There's no clear point for the `Serializer<T>` instance to point to itself. You can easily use `this` and cast it to `T`. Also, unless your `ToXML` method implements some really generic XML serialization algorithm (like processing the current instance via reflection), you should make it `virtual` and place the specific implementations in `Serializer<T>`'s ancestors.

Also, I would also object your approach to inheritance. If your `Account` class is in fact a single purpose account *serializer*, then name it so (`AccountSerializer`). If not, and `Account` represents an actual account, then yes, from an independent reader's point of view you are mixing two primary concepts: a business object (`Account`) and some technical mechanism (`Serializer<T>`).

If you have a general-purpose serialization algorith, why don't you just have a separate, non-abstract `Serializer<T>` class, accepting `T` instances in `ToXML()`? You will end up with better separation of concerns.

> Is there a way to inherit the methods of an interface like a class (no implementing/overriding).

No. Interfaces are *interfaces*, not classes than embed particular code.

Answer (score 0):

If your code in the Abstract class will not change just to serialize the object, this approach doesn't make sense, Serialization you do not need to know the object type (Especially if your using xml which means building a easy to access string).

If you want the Serialization only available to certain objects make an interface i.e

```
public interface ISerialize
{
}

 public class Account : ISerialize
{
}
```

and then create an Extension method

```
public static class ExtenstionMethods
{
     public static string ToXml(this ISerialize obj)
     {
     // code to build xml string
     }
}
```

This way you can do what you want to do because Account is of the Interface and the ExtensionMethods will only work on that Interface, thus you only need the code in the ExtensionMethods class and then include the namespace wherever you want to use the "ToXml()" etc

```
Account account = new Account();
Console.WriteLine(account.ToXML());
```